# How to install Adafruit-GPIO library in Docker

Tags: docker, adafruit

I'm new to Docker, so there could be something I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to install `Adafruit-GPIO` in a container, but I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm building the file locally on a Windows 10 pc, using Powershell.

I'v made sure that the GCC is installed correctly and it is. I've been searching online for an answer and there isn't much to go on.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM balenalib/raspberry-pi-debian-python:3.7.2

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc
RUN pip3 install adafruit-gpio
```

I'm expecting the file to compile and work successfully. Instead I'm getting this,

```
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qfol0jyh/spidev/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"
'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-i37a5wvt/install-record.txt -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'spidev' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.7
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c spidev_module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.7/spidev_module.o
    In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                     from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:11,
                     from spidev_module.c:28:
    /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
     #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qfol0jyh/spidev/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);cod
e=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-i37a5wvt/install-record.txt --single-version-external
ly-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-qfol0jyh/spidev/
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `build-essential` to replace `gcc` could make you work, see [official git](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO#adafruit-python-gpio-library).

In fact, when build some source code, always better to install `build-essential` because it will not only install `gcc`, but also some dev package. Your error `fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory` just because miss these dev package.

In a word, next will works for you:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential
```